# java new operator in Array

Tags: java

I find the new operator a bit confusing. My understanding now is that

```
new ClassName(...)
```

is to make an instance and call the Class' constructor. But what does new do when initiating an Array? For example, I feel the two new operators below are different, but can't explain clearly.

```
Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];
staff[0] = new Employee(...);
```

Are there any difference?

Thanks.

Comment: staff[0] is a reference to your `Employee` object.

Comment: They're exactly the same.. `staff[0]` is of type `Employee`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];
```

Is initializing your array of `Employee`s with 3 "places" which can hold references to your `Employee` objects.
That means it reserves 3 times the space needed for one object/instance of your `Employee` class (e.g. 10byte) in the RAM (=> 30 byte). 
But your array is initalized with "null".
While `staff[0] = new Employee(...);` is creating a reference to your newly created object of type `Employee`.
[image: arrays]

Comment: Thanks. Does "new Employee[3]" reserve place for 3 references (kind of a C pointer?) or actually space for 3 Employee objects (but not actually creating them) ?

Comment: You're welcome. The system (Java Virtual Machine) allocates the memory needed for 3 Employees, not just the references.
E.g. `int[] arr = new int[10]; // allocates memory for 10 integers`
For more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 4):

`new Employee[3]` creates an array that can hold references to 3 Employee instances. Each of them is initialized to null. `staff[0] = new Employee(...);` creates an `Employee` instance and assigns its reference to the first index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the class' constructor, an instance (object) of that class is created. The "new" keyword is what tells the compiler to create an object. An array is a class and you make objects of type Array of SomeClass. You need to use the keyword "new" because you are still creating an object.